# Replace a character with other character at a specific position in a long string and save that changed string as new string recursively in R

Tags: r

I have a long string

```
string <- "bdbakdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck"
```

Now I want to replace character positions listed in "replace_position" with V1 and save new string as new file named as change in position no. iteratively for each position changed

```
replace_position <- c(4, 5, 19, 24, 30, 36, 39, 40)

v1 <- c("E", "N", "M", "o", "p", "q", "r", "S")
write.csv("4.csv")
write.csv("5.csv")
```

and so on..

Expected outcome:

```
4th_string <- "bdbEkdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck"
5th_string <- "bdbaNdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck"
```

19th and so on
Is there any other way to do it using for loop or regexp in R

Comment: What do you want to replace with

Comment: Provide reproducible example data `dput(string)`, and expected output.

Comment: Not clear what is meant by "recursively".

Comment: I want to replace with a different character for each position mentioned. like 4th with E, 5th with N, 19th with M, 24th with o etc. and save it to as new string for each replacement. expected output 4th_string <- bdbEkdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck; 5th_string <- bdbaNdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck

Answer (score 1):

If the intention is to replace the characters at the position with a single character, then use `substring`

```
for(i in seq_along(replace_position))
  substr(str1, replace_position[i], replace_position[i]) <- "#"
str1
#[1] "bdb##dljbbkhkcksbf#svcj#vksnc#ndkbk#bc##ck"
```

and as @RuiBarradas mentioned, this can be written back to the file with `cat`

```
cat(str1, file = "file1.txt")
```

---

Based on the OP's comments, if the values replaced are different based on different position, then just change the rhs of the assignment

```
for(i in seq_along(replace_position))
  substr(str1, replace_position[i], replace_position[i]) <- v1[i] 

str1
#[1] "bdbENdljbbkhkcksbfMsvcjovksncpndkbkqbcrSck"
```

#### data

```
replace_position <- c(4, 5, 19, 24, 30, 36, 39, 40)
str1 <- "bdbakdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck"
v1 <- c("E", "N", "M", "o", "p", "q", "r", "S")
```

Comment: You are forgetting the file write (in the loop), but I would use `cat`, not `write.csv` like the OP posted. Upvote, anyway.

Comment: Hi Rui Barradas, thanks for your efforts. I have just asked in another way that I need to save each replacement at a time. expected ouput: expected output 4th_string <- bdbEkdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck; 5th_string <- bdbaNdljbbkhkcksbfjsvcjsvksnclndkbksbcsbck

Comment: Have any clue for multiple replacements in a string at different positions?